# How to set a USB drive to read-only mode

Tags: usb, read-only, hdparm

I want to set my usb drive to read-only mode bo avoid files being modified by others.

```
root@test-OptiPlex-360:~# hdparm -r /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
root@test-OptiPlex-360:~# 
root@test-OptiPlex-360:~# 
root@test-OptiPlex-360:~# 
root@test-OptiPlex-360:~# hdparm -r1 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting readonly to 1 (on)
 readonly      =  1 (on)
```

Then, I unplug and plugin it again, and hdparm shows the read-only flag is not set.

```
root@test-OptiPlex-360:~# hdparm -r /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

I can still modify files stored in the usb drive.
Why hdparm doesn't work here? How can I set my usb drive to read-only mode?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider letting the *disk* `/dev/sdc` remain read-write but *mounting* it readony with `sudo mount -o ro,other_options_as_needed /dev/sdc mount_point`. For example,

```
sudo mount -o ro,dmask=0022,fmask=0133,gid=$(id -g),uid=$(id -u) /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I will borrow the usb drive to others, so the drive will be plugged in an other computer, maybe many computers. I can also store files in ISO 9660 file system and burn to usb drive by dd command. It's read only, but I don't think it's convenient. I want to find some easy way to set a usb drive in read-only mode, and when I want to modify files in the drive, I can just set the drive in read-write mode. Thanks for your reply again.

Comment: ISO 9660 is not really readonly -- nothing stops the user from copying the files to their own machine, modifying them, making a new ISO and `dd`-ing it back to the flash drive. In general, when file integrity is a concern the recommended approach is to use checksums distributed on a secure channel.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out how to make a persistent USB drive read only, I can change permissions of the casper-rw persistence file to read only, and it says it is read only, but it is not.

Comment: @YanchuanNian, When file integrity is a concern the recommended approach is to send flles and checksums via a secure channel. Distribution via USB is not possible to make really safe. If *you* can switch the USB drive between read-only and read-write mode, *other people* can do it too.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wanted to do the same thing, and, essentially, I have the desired result. I have a Live-USB set up, and I didn't want people touching the files on the other end. So I tried `hdparm -r1 sdb` and it *did* what I wanted it to do. You, now, cannot access the files when it is plugged into the computer - you cannot access the drive at all. It doesn't show. Which leads me to asking another question - why? I have no idea.

But the good news is that I can still boot from the drvie and it works all fine. There is just one anomally going on - when I read through `hdparm /dev/sdb/` it still says

```
read only        = 0 (off)
```

which is strange. But your question has been answered!